# Form Update - Null Field

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm facing a problem on updating a resource. In an admin dashboard of my company we have access to the users and we can edit their data. Mostly we won't update the password, so the field will be null, but the database doesn't accept the password to be null. Is there any rule to add to my FormRequest that ignore a field if the field is null? I have searched the docs but couldn't find how to do it.

The html method if post with `method('patch')`.

Request:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => ['bail', 'required', 'numeric'],
        'name' => ['bail', 'required', 'string'],
        'user_name' => ['bail', 'required', 'string'],
        'email' => ['bail', 'required', 'email:rfc,dns,filter'],
        'password' => ['nullable'],
        'groups' => ['bail', 'required'],
        'groups.*' => ['numeric'],
    ];
}
```

EDIT 1: I could remove password from the validated data if the password is null, but doesn't seem it's the proper way to do it.

```php
// If the user inserted a new password, HASH it
if ($validated_data['password'] !== null)
{
    $validated_data['password'] = Hash::make($validated_data['password']);
} else {
    unset($validated_data['password']);
}

dd($validated_data);
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

usually user provider the password only when he want to change it ...

so, in your rules:

```
 'password' => ['nullable'],
```

make sense ...

in the controller you could use [rule-required-if](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-if):

```
$old_password=$user?$user->password:null;

Validator::make($validated_data, [
    'password' => Rule::requiredIf(old_password==null),
]);

if ($validated_data['password'] !== null)
{
    $validated_data['password'] = Hash::make($validated_data['password']);
}
```

i strongly recommend that  there is no unset for the password

Answer (score 1):

Try not passing the "password" param in the request payload. Hope you know that [Laravel's QB update method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updates) does allow updating selective fields. When you don't pass, it won't get updated.